# Difference between calling back bean method using parenthesis and without parenthesis in jsf?

Tags: jsf

what is the difference between

```
  <h:commandLink actionListener="#{serviceProviderBean.method}" value="Save" />
```

and

```
 <h:commandLink actionListener="#{serviceProviderBean.method()}" value="Save" />
```

is both invoke same method or any error in above code

Comment: if both works... :) I think it relates to the used EL parser version. Earlier version did not support calling methods using braces and would try to resolve "method" to a get or set method. You can also add parameters into the braces if I remember that correctly (for ex. the current object in a table).

Comment: how to know  EL parser version ?

Comment: it is part of the application server / servlet container / tomcat / thing. For tomcat the EL spec version is listed here: http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html - the EL parser can be reconfigured. The JBoss EL was quite famous before braces came officially into the EL spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second will not work under tomcat6, it will work with tomcat7/jSF2

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine. The second one is being used for passing params like

```
<h:commandLink actionListener="#{serviceProviderBean.save(someBean.someOption)}" 
   value="Save" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you also have to use the method **with** braces, when you want to use a method returning a boolean value, but don't have a matching property defined in the bean.

I had that situation today. 
My xhtml page has a `<h:panelGroup ...>` with the `rendered="#{bean.isLoggedIn}"` attribute. The `isLoggedIn` method, calls the method of the boundary, so the bean does not have the matching property `private boolean isLoggedIn`.
I got a exception because of the missing property.
After adding the braces to the rendered attribute making it to `rendered="#{bean.isLoggedIn()}"` it's working correctly.

Anyway. The method got removed by now, because my bean should not do business logic stuff :D

Comment: You got a typo and/or misunderstanding here. The machting property would be `private boolean loggedIn` and not `isLoggedIn`. Nevertheless, your point is just wrong. It just comes down to the EL parser version. For example, I can freely use `#{bean.searchPerson}`, while those is not a property. It is a method without any parameter instead.